# multi aggregated sql query functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.username, t.pack_id, COUNT( t.id ) transaction_count
FROM  `transaction` t
INNER JOIN  `user` u ON t.customer_id = u.id
GROUP BY (
t.customer_id
)
HAVING transaction_count >1
```

and I am trying to get the username and transactions for all users that has a transaction_count > 1
and the first transaction created is with quantity of 3 and I want to get a list like this:

```
username:
    transaction1
    transaction2

username2:
    transaction3
    transaction4
    transaction5
```

is this even possible? my transaction table looks like this:

[image]

and here's my user table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't get output like that from MySQL, the closest one is probably:

```
user1 trans1
user1 trans2
user1 trans3
user1 trans4
user2 trans1
user2 trans2
user2 trans3
```

And to do that one, it would be simple `inner join` like you did. But, to apply these two conditions you want, it gets a bit complicated

```
SELECT ux.*,tx.* FROM
(
  SELECT u.*,count(t1.id) as transaction_count FROM users u
  INNER JOIN transaction t1 ON t1.customer_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s1.customer_id,MIN(s1.created) as min_date
    FROM transaction s1
    GROUP BY s1.customer_id
  ) t2 ON t2.customer_id = u.id 
  INNER JOIN transaction t3 ON t3.customer_id = u.id AND t3.created = t2.min_date AND t3.quatity>3
  GROUP BY u.id
  HAVING count(t1.id)>3
) ux
INNER JOIN transaction tx ON tx.customer_id = ux.id
ORDER BY ux.id,tx.id
```

short explanation:

transaction s1 in subquery t2 is used to find date of first transaction per user

transaction t3 is used to filter users by quantity in first transaction (thanks t2.min_date)

transaction t1 is used to count transactions per user (and filter these of 3 or less in having clause)

subquery ux holds users that comply both conditions

transaction tx finally adds transactions per user to the output

---

**edit:** My mistake, I thought you wanted transaction_count>3 condition, but I see you typed transaction_count>1 ; No big deal, query just gets one line simpler, that condition is handled by INNER JOIN t3 anyway(INNER JOIN won't pass user that have no matching transaction), thus I will use transaction t1 just to count transactions into transactions_count column

```
SELECT ux.*,tx.* FROM
(
  SELECT u.*,count(t1.id) as transaction_count FROM users u
  INNER JOIN transaction t1 ON t1.customer_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s1.customer_id,MIN(s1.created) as min_date
    FROM transaction s1
    GROUP BY s1.customer_id
  ) t2 ON t2.customer_id = u.id 
  INNER JOIN transaction t3 ON t3.customer_id = u.id AND t3.created = t2.min_date AND t3.quatity>3
  GROUP BY u.id
) ux
INNER JOIN transaction tx ON tx.customer_id = ux.id
ORDER BY ux.id,tx.id
```